# Is there any advantage of IBM RAD 7.5 over Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, fortify, ibm-rad-7.5

I am looking to work on coding, which one is preferable IBM RAD or Eclipse, Supportive concept or logic please..

Comment: RAD 7.5 is ancient and is based on Eclipse 3.4. The current release of Eclipse is 4.8. Which to use is a matter of opinion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and RAD both are developed by IBM. Eclipse is open source product and free for download but RAD is IBM's licensed business product and you have to buy it. RAD is developed on the top of eclipse and hence it has lots of in-build utilities than Eclipse. But in Eclipse you can add utilities by adding plug-ins from various open source for free.

Now its up to you whether you want to buy RAD or get Eclipse for free. In RAD java JKD is pre-install hence you no need to install JDK in advance but to use Eclipse you have to first install JDK in your system.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, It looks quite informative. Thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: Eclipse is being developed under the umbrella of the Eclipse Foundation, independently of IBM. The majority of Eclipse developers are not IBM employees, see e. g. [Platform](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.platform/who) or [JDT](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.jdt/who).